Applying the Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem without explicitly building a sequence of functions.
Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$ denote an arbitrary non-empty open set.
The classical formulation of the Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem (LDCT, for short) is as follows.
LDCT. Let $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ be a sequence of real-valued measurable functions defined on $\Omega$ such that $f_n \to f$ pointwise almost everywhere as $n \to \infty$. If there exists a function $g \in L^1(\Omega)$ such that $|f_n(x)| \leqslant g(x)$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$ and $x \in \Omega$, then
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_\Omega f_n(x) \, dx = \int_\Omega f(x) \, dx. $$
My problem. Consider a fixed function $f \in L^p$ and let $x_0 \in \mathbb R^n$ be an arbitrary element. My goal is to study
$$ \int_{B(x_0,r)} |f(y)|^p \, dy  \quad \text{ as }\quad r \to \infty.$$
To do this, I've applied the LDCT in the following way. Obviously, for every $y \in \mathbb R^n$ and $r > 0$ we have that
$$|f(y)|^p \, \chi_{B(x_0,r)}(y) \leqslant |f(y)|^p.$$ Moreover, we also know that $|f|^p \in L^1$, by hypothesis. Hence, by the LDCT, it follows that
$$ \lim_{r \to \infty} \int_{B(x_0,r)} |f(y)|^p \, dy = \int_{\mathbb R^n} \lim_{r \to \infty} |f(y)|^p \, \chi_{B(x_0,r)}(y) \, dy = \int_{\mathbb R^n}|f(y)|^p \, dy = \| f \|_p^p. $$
My concerns. After reviewing my approach to this problem, I noticed that I am not (at least, directly) using the formulation of the LDCT that I've presentend above. Formally, I should build a sequence of functions and I am not doing this. Intuitively my conclusion seems correct, but I would like to be sure that I can apply the LDCT in the way I did above.
Basically, I would like to know if my approach to the problem is correct and if so, why. In other words, why is it possible to apply the LDCT in the way I did above?
Thanks for any help in advance.

Your approach is correct and you don‘t have to build a sequence: $r\rightarrow\infty$ means taking the Limit for every sequence $r_k\rightarrow \infty$. So you check that your argument works for every such sequence (easy) and hence you can just let $r \rightarrow\infty$

@HyperbolicPDEfriend Is this related to Heine's definition of the limit of a function ?

Yes, it is basically that

Thanks for your help.

You do not need dominated convergence here, use monotone convergence theorem.

@daw Indeed you're right that I could've used the MCT instead. Is there any particular reason why you would prefer the MCT instead of the DCT?

Your approach is correct because more generally, for a point $a$ having a countable neighborhood basis in a space $A$ (like here $\infty$ in $[0,\infty]$ with its usual topology) and any function $F:A\to B$ (where $B$ is another topological space, like here $\Bbb R$), if $F(a_n)\to L$ for every sequence $(a_n)$ converging to $a$, then $\lim_{x\to a}F(x)=L$.

I agree with @daw about MCT. It is more canonical here. Say e.g. you only know that $0 = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f\chi_{B_r(0)}~\mathrm{d}x$ for all $r>0$ and some $f \in L^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, $f \geq 0$ and you want to conclude that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f~\mathrm{d}x=0$ by letting $r \rightarrow \infty$ (happens e.g. in the proof of the fundamental lemma of calculus of variations). You might see that DCT does not help here, while MCT is conclusive.
